# Как с помощью QT вывести на монитор 10-битное изображение?

Tags: c++, qt, изображения

Недавно появился снэпшот `Qt 5.13`, в котором у `QImage` стал доступен формат `QImage::Format_Grayscale16`. Около года назад мне уже приходилось работать с `QImage`, но тогда речь шла только о 8-битах на пиксель. Так как на работе есть 10-битный монитор, я решил попробовать создать и вывести на него градиент 1024x400, в котором каждый пиксель должен быть на тон светлее предыдущего (2^10=1024). Сформировав `QByteArray` следующим образом:

```
QByteArray *ArrayGenerator::gen10bitArr()
{
    QByteArray *arr = new QByteArray();
    uint8_t partA;
    uint8_t partB;
    for (int row = 0; row < 400; row++) {
        for (uint16_t color = 0; color < 1024; color++) {
                partA = static_cast<uint8_t>((color &0xFF00) >> 8);
                partB = static_cast<uint8_t>(color &0x00FF);
                arr->append (partA);
                arr->append (partB);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Я попытался сформировать `QImage` так же, как делал это прежде:

```
QImage &MainWindow::gen10bitImg(QByteArray*data, int width, int height)
{
    QImage * img = new QImage((uchar*)data->data (),
                              width, height, 2048, QImage::Format_Grayscale16);
    img->save ("image.png");
    return *img;
}
```

Однако, результат был неожиданным, вместо градиента на 1024px, сформировалось целых четыре по 256px:

[image: Градиенты]

Такое ощущение, что `QImage` сформировался только по четным байтам из `QByteArray`.
Как можно побороть подобное? Кто-нибудь уже работал с `QImage::Format_Grayscale16`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне представляется, что вы работаете на little endian машине и перепутали порядок байт:

```
 partA = static_cast<uint8_t>(color &0x00FF);
 partB = static_cast<uint8_t>((color &0xFF00) >> 8);
```

Comment: Я тоже так подумал сначала, но нет, в таком случае выводятся полосы цветов 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев Как это выглядит?

Comment: хмм, вообще странно, почему-то 5 полос с цветом от 0 до 4 ...
https://yadi.sk/i/NYH0V1rYXLUTIQ
цвета 0 и 4 по 127 пикселей шириной, единственное, что замерял я по полученному пикселю через QColor::fromRgba(QPoint(x, y)), а надо fromRgba64()

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев У вас на картинке не видно никаких полос. Только два градиента. Причем нижний похож на правильный. Заметете, что значение 1024 - это почти черный цвет, а не белый. Белый это 65535

Comment: Вы правы, я был очень невнимателен, действительно, если пикселей 1024 и в 16 битном контейнере задействовано только 10 бит, это не значит, что белый, это 2^10... Спасибо.
Теперь проблема в том, что визуально, эти два градиента совершенно не отличаются на 10-битном мониторе...